# Внесение данных в двумерный массив

Tags: c++, массивы

Пишу код, который обрабатывают вводимую с клавиатуры строку. В ней содержатся токены разделенные пробелами. Эти токены она помещает в двумерный массив. После обработки строки программа обрабатывает следующую. В чём проблема: после того как программа внесла первую партию токенов в массив, она начинает обрабатывать вторую группу токенов, и вместо того, чтобы заносить данные во второй элемент массива, она перезаписывает значения первых токенов на текущие. Код представлен ниже:

```
char string[MAX_INPUT_LENGTH];
char * countries[MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE][MAX_CLUSTER_SIZE];

size_t i = 0;
size_t j = 0;

char *delim = " ";
while(true) {
    i = 0;

    gets(string);

    char * token = strtok(string, delim);
    while(token != NULL) {
        cout << token << endl;
        countries[j][i] =  token;
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        i++;
    }

    if(i == 0) {
        break;
    }

    j++;
    token = "";
}

return a.exec();
```

Comment: потестил код, работает как ожидается. Правда это не совсем с++...

Comment: попробуй запустить в режиме отладки проследить за наполнением массива countries. у меня происходит какая-то чертовщина

Comment: Разберитесь как именно работает strtok и c строки. Все станет на свои места.

Comment: что здесь неверно?

Comment: в строке `countries[j][i] =  token;` Вы копируете просто указатель, а не строку.

Answer (score 1):

В этом коде сохраняются в массив указатели на одну и ту же строку.
Производится чтение строки в переменную `string` с её последующим разбором. В ходе разбора сохраняются указатели на фрагменты этой строки. Однако в следующей итерации в эту же строку производится чтение нового содержимого.

Возможные решения:

1. Хранить строки, а не указатели.
2. Производить "дочитывание" в массив `string` и сохранять указатели на него. Только в этом варианте массив `string` должен быть достаточного размера и нужно будет изменить работу с `strtok` (в общем первый вариант проще и понятнее).